# how to read character from an EditText view of Android

Tags: android

I want to read each character by character of the input user given in the Edittext (not right away) in android.

I found the inbuilt function "characterAt()" to read a character at a specific index but it is not helping my need.

Comment: For this kind of needs use `TextWatcher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

Then use `text.charAt(index).`

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextWatcher`

Like this...

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

`afterTextChanged()` method can be used to read the character entered one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Add a KeyListener if you want get character by character and set onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) handler.